# Replacing C++ vector with a C vector

Tags: c++, c

I have the following algorithm:

```
// Prim cu coada de prioritati si graful reprezentat printr-un array de vectori(matrice)
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <list>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std; 
# define INF 0x3f3f3f3f 

struct Edge {
    int destination;
    int weight;
};

Edge newEdge(int destination, int weight) {
    return { destination, weight };
};

// Adaugarea unei muchii
void addEdge(vector <Edge> adj[], int from, int to, int weight) 
{ 
    adj[from].push_back(newEdge(to, weight));
    adj[to].push_back(newEdge(from, weight));
};

// To compare two points 
bool cmp(const Edge& e1, const Edge& e2) { 
    return e1.weight >= e2.weight; 
};

// Printeaza cel mai scurt drum de la sursa(nodul parinte) la celelalte noduri
void primMST(vector<Edge> adj[], int V, int numberElemOp) 
{ 

    // Creaza o coada de prioritati pentru a stoca nodurile. 
    // Pentru sintaxa ca data trecuta vezi: http://geeksquiz.com/implement-min-heap-using-stl/ 
    priority_queue< Edge, vector <Edge> , decltype(&cmp) > pq{cmp}; 

    int src = 0; // Nodul 0 este nodul parinte

    // vector pentru retinerea arborelui construit
    int parent[V]; 
    // Key values used to pick minimum weight edge in cut 

    // valorile utilizate pentru a alege minimul
    int key[V]; 

    // Vector care arata ce noduri au intrat in MST
    bool inMST[V];

    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)  {
        key[i] = INF;
        inMST[i] = false;
        parent[i] = -1;    
    }

    numberElemOp += (3 * V);

    // Insereaza nodul parinte in coada de prioritati si pune cheia pe 0
    pq.push(newEdge(src, 0));
    key[src] = 0; 

    numberElemOp += 3;

    /* Pana cand se goleste coada */
    while (!pq.empty()) 
    { 
        // Primul nod din pereche este cheia minima, extrage cheia din coada de prioritati.
        // Numele nodului este stocat in a 2 a pereche (asa trebuie facut ca sa ai nodurile sortate dupa cheie
        // cheia trebuie sa fie prima valoare din pereche)
        int u = pq.top().destination; 
        pq.pop(); 

        inMST[u] = true; // Nod inclus in MST


        numberElemOp += 3;
        // Traverseaza toti vecinii lui u
        for (auto x : adj[u]) 
        { 
            // Ia numele si costul nodului vecin cu u
            int v = x.destination; 
            int weight = x.weight; 

            numberElemOp += 3;
            // Daca v nu este in MST si costul muchiei (u,v) este mai mic decat cheia lui v
            if (inMST[v] == false && key[v] > weight) 
            { 
                // Updateaza v
                key[v] = weight; 
                pq.push(newEdge(v, key[v])); 
                parent[v] = u; 
                numberElemOp += 7;
            } 
        } 
    } 

    // Printeaza muchiile msg-ului
    for (int i = 1; i < V; ++i) 
        printf("%d - %d\n", parent[i], i);

    printf("Numar operatii elementare: %d", numberElemOp);
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int numberElemOp;
    int V = 9; 
    numberElemOp += 1;
    vector<Edge> adj[V]; 

    addEdge(adj, 0, 1, 4); 
    addEdge(adj, 0, 7, 8); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 2, 8); 
    addEdge(adj, 1, 7, 11); 
    addEdge(adj, 2, 3, 7); 
    addEdge(adj, 2, 8, 2); 
    addEdge(adj, 2, 5, 4); 
    addEdge(adj, 3, 4, 9); 
    addEdge(adj, 3, 5, 14); 
    addEdge(adj, 4, 5, 10); 
    addEdge(adj, 5, 6, 2); 
    addEdge(adj, 6, 7, 1); 
    addEdge(adj, 6, 8, 6); 
    addEdge(adj, 7, 8, 7); 

    primMST(adj, V, numberElemOp); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The issue is that I am not allowed to use C++ and I must use C. This is kind of a bummer as C does not have vector and priority_queue. or any structures like this already implemented.

I tried toying a little bit with my own implementation of Vector but in the end I couldn't manage to make it work.

Is there a way I can replace vector and/or priority_queue with something in C? Does anyone already have an vector/priority_queue implementation in C that would make this work?

Comment: `int parent[V];` is an error in Standard C++, the dimension of arrays must be known at compile-time

Comment: There's no easy answer to this question: C doesn't come with any data structures, you will have to either write your own code for a Priority Queue or use some freely available data structure code.

Comment: @M.M v is known, it is 9 in this case. My issue with the vectors itself is the lack of push back and other methods that makes this easier

Comment: `V` is a function parameter in this code which doesn't count as "known at compile time"

Comment: @M.M so the compiler I am using is a little lenient and lets me get away with it even though a C compiler wouldn't ?

Comment: `int parent[V]` is allowed in Standard C but not Standard C++ . Some C++ compilers allow it as a  non-standard extension.

Comment: You're going to have hard time with approach like this. Don't think *how to copy* C++ into C. Learn how to solve a problem in C from basics. Learn how to solve problems without object-oriented programming support. It will pay off in time if you understand for example what `push_back` really does with the array.

Comment: There is no direct substitute for a priority queue in C. You will have to write your own implementation You can find some references for this online.. For a vector, you also need to write your own implementation, which can be done by a singly linked list - having the functions push_back and pop_back.

Comment: Have a look at this. It is rudimental and uses some C++ syntax, e.g. passing of parameters by reference, but you should, be able to adapt it. https://bitbucket.org/fabiocannizzo/fe5226/src/master/InputNumberArrayFun2.cpp

Comment: C has struct. For example, you can create a struct "myVector" with a void* tab, size, memory_size, size_of_a_element, ... and then create functions as create_myVector (myVector*, ...), push_bask_myVector (myVector*, ...) ... This kind of things were currently used before emergence of C++, or before C++ compilers were available in companies ... (before internet). A lot of work now useless with C++

Comment: Note the duplicate. One of the more interesting pointers in the answers is the [c-generic-library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/c-generic-library/).

Comment: Sadly I can't use that, has to be written by me... which is more than I have time for :D oh well 4 it is! thx guys

Comment: Your very last sentence states *Does anyone already have an vector/priority_queue implementation in C that would make this work?*